# Where are my SQL Server check constraints not working when doing joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, check-constraints

I have a large amount of data separated into tables by state in SQL Server 2019.  I have a check constraint on each table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StateData_TN] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_StateData_TN_State] CHECK (([State] = 'TN'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StateData_TN] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_StateData_TN_State]
GO
```

I then have a view that combines all of the "state" tables for querying like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_StateData] 
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.StateData_AK WHERE State = 'AK'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.StateData_AL WHERE State = 'AL'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.StateData_AR WHERE State = 'AR'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.StateData_AZ WHERE State = 'AZ'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.StateData_CA WHERE State = 'CA'
    etc...
```

If I run either of these queries, the query plan shows that it only hits the `StateData_TN` table:

```
SELECT SD.RecordId
FROM dbo.vw_StateData SD
WHERE SD.state = 'TN'

SELECT C.CustomerId, SD.RecordId
FROM dbo.Customer C
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_StateData SD ON C.State = SD.state 
                               AND C.Zip5 = SD.zipcode 
                               AND C.StandardizedAddress = SD.standardizedaddress
WHERE C.StoreNum = 1000 AND C.State = 'TN'
```

However, if I run the second query without the state limiter (remove: AND C.State = 'TN'), it queries every single table.  This happens even though every address for store #1000 is in Tennessee.

Is there any way to set this up in a way that it doesn't hit tables where the state is not in the table it is joining to?  There is a huge difference in speed between the queries with and without the "AND C.State = 'TN'"

Comment: You should have one common table, for all states' data.

Comment: Why do you have separated tables? Your life would be much easier with a single table. Faster queries. Shorter, simpler SQL.

Comment: This looks like a partitioned view setup, which I wouldn't have thought anyone would still be implementing in 2020 (even though it's still supported). Not sure a partitioned table would do much better here, but have you tried?

Comment: It was set up this way years ago, and I am not 100% sure on the logic.  I can tell you that each state has millions of rows and hundreds of columns.  I think at the time it was definitely faster to deal with this way.  I have not tried switching it to a single table or a partitioned table as of yet.

Comment: Is it always the case that a StoreNum is associated with just one state?  If so you could try something like `SELECT C.CustomerId, SD.RecordId
FROM dbo.Customer C
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_StateData SD ON C.State = SD.state 
                               AND C.Zip5 = SD.zipcode 
                               AND C.StandardizedAddress = SD.standardizedaddress
WHERE C.StoreNum = 1000 AND C.State = (SELECT State FROM Customer  WHERE StoreNum = 1000)` or possibly better would be to split in to two queries. One to get the state and assign it to a variable and then use that in the next query

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  In most cases a store would have only one state, but there are some with more than one (never more than 2 or 3).

Comment: The issue is that unless there is a predicate on the state at compile time the only way you are going to get the state elimination is if there is a nested loops plan but that may not be desirable. You could try changing the `INNER JOIN ` to `INNER LOOP JOIN ` and evaluate how that performs

Comment: Could you share the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I run the second query without the state limiter (remove: AND C.State = 'TN'), it queries every single table. This happens even though every address for store #1000 is in Tennessee.

I am just baffled by this observation.  How does the database know where store #1000 unless it looks?

By providing the `state`, you are telling the database that this is the case.

I think you would be much better off with a single table and an index on `store`.

Comment: I'm okay with the lookup on the customer table, it's the lookup on the StateData table that is the problem.  It should know by the customer table that there is only one state (for that query).